# How to use OpenGL ES with GLFW on windows?

Tags: windows, opengl-es, glfw

Since `NVIDIA DRIVE product supports the OpenGL ES 2 and 3 specifications`, I want to run OpenGL ES code on Windows 10 with GTX 2070, which will elimated a
Also, GLFW support configuration like `glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CLIENT_API, GLFW_OPENGL_ES_API)`. Is it possible to use GLFW to run OpenGL ES code on Windows 10?

Comment: It is possible according to the documentation(https://www.glfw.org/docs/3.3/context_guide.html). What library do you use for extension loading?

Comment: @tuket Currently glad is used.

Answer (score 5):

First of all, make sure you have downloaded glad with GL ES.

https://glad.dav1d.de/

For the glfw part, you need to set the `GLFW_CLIENT_API` window [hints](https://www.glfw.org/docs/3.3.2/window_guide.html#window_hints_wnd).

```c
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CLIENT_API, GLFW_OPENGL_ES_API);
```

And also choose wich version you want, for example:

```c
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 2);
```

Then specify the kind of context. In the case of OpenGL ES, according to the [documentation](https://www.glfw.org/docs/3.3.2/window_guide.html#GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE_attrib), it must be `GLFW_OPENGL_ANY_PROFILE`.

```c
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_ANY_PROFILE);
```

> GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE indicates the OpenGL profile used by the context.
> This is GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE or GLFW_OPENGL_COMPAT_PROFILE if the
> context uses a known profile, or GLFW_OPENGL_ANY_PROFILE if the OpenGL
> profile is unknown or the context is an OpenGL ES context. Note that
> the returned profile may not match the profile bits of the context
> flags, as GLFW will try other means of detecting the profile when no
> bits are set.

However, `GLFW_OPENGL_ANY_PROFILE` is already the default value, so you don't really need to set it.